# Solving/approximating 2-D Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains, approximation, steady-state

I came across the following continuous time Markov chain and would like to know if there is a good way to solve/approximate steady state distribution of the states.

Note that the horizontal right and left arrows has rate $\lambda$ and $k\gamma, k=1,2,3,...$, respectively.

The vertical down and up arrows has rate $\mu$ and $k\delta, k=1,2,3,...$, respectively.

The red and blue arrows made the problem difficult. They have rates $\mu$ and $\lambda$, respectively.

It is easy to see that this Markov chain is positively recurrent. But how to solve/approximate the steady state distribution? Please provide ideas/thoughts/references.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what the collection of transitions looks like in full here. In any case without detailed balance which doesn't appear to hold here, you are stuck with numerics by truncating the state space.